# Resolve bookmark created in iOS app in Share Extension

Tags: swift, uikit, nsurl

I create a URL bookmark with `URL.bookmarkData(options: [], includingResourceValuesForKeys: [.localizedNameKey])` and resolve it with `NSURL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData, options: [], relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: nil) as URL`. This works fine within my main app, but when sharing the bookmarkData via an App Group with my Share Extension, it gives the error "The file couldn't be opened because you don't have permission to view it.". Is there any way I can do this?